# Error installing Perl CGI module from cpan

Tags: perl, apache2, cgi, cpan

I get the following results when doing `cpan install CGI` on `Ubuntu 10.4`.

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/tmpdir.t             (Wstat: 0 Tests: 9 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   3, 6, 8
t/url.t                (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=39, Tests=695,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.45 usr  0.11 sys +  1.19 cusr  0.21 csys =      1.96 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/39 test programs. 0/695 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  MARKSTOS/CGI.pm-3.55.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports MARKSTOS/CGI.pm-3.55.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 MARKSTOS/CGI.pm-3.55.tar.gz                  : make_test NO
```

And `cpan force install` also create same results. Has anyone had this error, does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Provide the verbose test output. Run `cpanm --look CGI` (or `look CGI` in the CPAN shell); `perl Makefile.PL`; `make`; `prove -bf`

Comment: Solved this be running upgrade in CPAN

Answer (score 5):

Don't install modules from CPAN if you have a packet manager. This may cause problems with update or with other modules.
Just use:

```
apt-get install libcgi-pm-perl
```

OR, if you can't find the package with needed module, you must make a package first ( you need to install dh-make-perl package for that)

sample of creating debian/ubuntu package:

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MA/MARKSTOS/CGI.pm-3.63.tar.gz
tar -xvpf CGI.pm-3.63.tar.gz
cd CGI.pm-3.63/
dh-make-perl
debian/rules binary
```

and install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```